# node.js callbacks, nested functions, how to refactor

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node.js and Express. I want to create a Vendor and make it associated with City object.

// City Model
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
var CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
```

// Vendor Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var VendorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    city: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City' }
});


mongoose.model('Vendor', VendorSchema);
```

//routes/index.js

vendor.save(function) is inside City.findOne(function) which looks a bit ugly. I want the code to follow Single Responsibility Rule or let's say make the code more clean. What will be the best practice to write these nested callback functions?

Thank you very much.

```
mongoose.model('City', CitySchema);

router.post('/vendor', function(req, res, next){
    var vendor = new Vendor();
    vendor.name = req.body.name;

    City.findOne({name:req.body.city}, function(err, city) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        vendor.city = city;

        vendor.save(function(err, vendor) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            res.json(vendor);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Model.populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate):

```
var Vendor = mongoose.model('Vendor', VendorSchema);

var opts = [{ path: 'city', match: { name: req.body.city}}];

var vendor = new Vendor({
    name: req.body.name
});

Vendor.populate(vendor, opts, function (err, vendor) {
     if (err) { return next(err); }
            res.json(vendor);
  });
```